# How to confirm Data (Dates) from a database and show a image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql, database

So i have a website and i want to connect my database to the html.

I want my website to works like this, when there is an event the website shows a image. but in order to do this, i need to  make a database which store the dates of the events, it should work with JavaScript, So the JavaScript takes current time and then goes to SQL Server and look for the Current dates, if the Date matches the Dates in the Database then the JavaScript will Show a image in the html, if it doesn't match then it will show anotherimage..

I Don't know how to do this, if someone kind provide me source code for this.. 
If Anyone Helpfull please help me.

Comment: Did you experiment with the `Date` object in JavaScript ? If not, go read about it. Are you experienced in AJAX ? if not, go read about it. Are you experienced in SQL Server querying ? if not, go read about it.  

Once you read about those subjects or mastered them, you should have the tools to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have some knowledge about

SQL Query for storing data

Server side programming language "you need to choose one such as php, python, asp.net, and so on"

Ajax to communicate between server-side and client side "without reloading the page for example"

client-side web development HTML CSS and javascript.

there are a lot of tutorials to start with.

good luck

Comment: Could you provide me a link plz

Comment: Which programming language would you like to start with? if you are an absolute beginner and you would like to start with web development. I would suggest you to begin with php. About the tutorial link, just jump to the YouTube search first about how to install php and Apache server. if you don't have MySQL server, you need to install MySQL server and workbench. After you finish all the installations, then jump to the YouTube  again some of them good, but still it is free source. if you are willing to pay, I do recommend lynda.com

Comment: I am not absolute beginner i have some know of web development, like html, css and JavaScript,, ,and THANK for the Tip,,, Really Appropriate the HELP